# fetching Error while installing mysql in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu-14.04

While installing Mysql in ubuntu getting error like

> unable to fetch some archives

how to solve this ?

Comment: And getting these type of error's too ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)

Comment: They are two different errors, one ios for installation, and one is when already installed. Please, be more specific with your question. For start, you can try uninstalling and installing again the MySQL packages

Comment: when i give this command i get  ps -ef|grep mysql
root      4487  4133  0 12:10 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql

Answer (score 2):

try to update and upgrade using the following script.

```
sudo apt-get update && upgrade
```

then try to execute the MySQL installation command.

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After that retry the install again.